# What is SomeType<T["someString"]> in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I just ran across [this](https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-redash/blob/bbb35e9041dc4c4bd09e269cc9ddc7f5cba2a0c7/packages/core/src/AnimationRunners.ts#L59) TypeScript annotation that I had never seen before, which simplified looks like this: `SomeType<T["someString"]>`. What is the `["someString"]` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a field name:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  someString: boolean;
}

interface SomeType<T> {
  someType: T;
}

const someValue: SomeType<SomeInterface['someString']>;
```

this will give `someValue.someType` the type `boolean`